# Do not post non answers

Tags: discussion

Especially if your "answer" is just a simple attempt to smack-talk elementary because it is a distro you do not like (or know how to use).

This is not constructive, gives the community work it could do without, and could pull the site down if it were not kept in check.

Answer (score 3):

While that's certainly a valid concern, I fail to see (1) what answers this post expects to get (i.e., are we abusing the Q&A platform as a forum?) and (2) how this would help users of the main site (are we hoping it shows up in the hot meta questions box in the sidebar?).

By the way, non-answers are probably the easiest posts to review, in my experience, at least when it comes to flagging. Not sure how much work it is, from the moderators side, to convert them into comments, but I'd expect SE to have mechanisms to facilitate this kind of action.

Comment: This post isn't seeking answers. Meta isn't a strict QnA section like the main site. Think of this post a reminder to those who are using the site improperly.

Comment: That's what I assumed (I was mostly making sure, and also raising the question so it would be explicitly addressed), but point (2) still applies. I can't see how this will effectively be even seen by those users who post non-answers as answers, let alone serve as a reminder. Do you expect them to visit meta, or am I overlooking some detail?

Comment: you're right they likely won't visit meta any time soon (and I did forget to make this a bulletin) but it might just deter at least one or two of them.

Comment: FYI, converting a post flagged as "not an answer" to a comment is typically one button push, maybe a second if it has comments itself.

Comment: I suspected as much, @LewisGoddard, thanks for confirming.